# Connectng to Postgres with Using windows security using NpgsqlConnection

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect with Postgres Database using Windows authentication.
Here are the details

This is the change made in pg_ident.conf

```
pg_ident
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
SSPI             domainusername         pgusername same as domainusername
```

This from pg_hba.conf

```
 pg_hba
    # IPv4 local connections for SSPI:
   # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256

#== lines for specific users for SSPI (or anything else) BEFORE the catchall lines ==

# IPv4 local connections for SSPI:
host    all             domainusername     127.0.0.1/32             ident  map=SSPI

# IPv6 local connections for SSPI:
host    all             domainusername    ::1/128                 ident  map=SSPI
#====================================================================


# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all         all         all             md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

In the postgres login a "login" is created with the same name as domainusername. The user has the login role.

```
Connection object
    NpgsqlConnection(@"Server = Servername;Port = 5432;Database = DBname; Integrated Security = True;");
```

When I try to run the exe the error that I get is

```
**'No password has been provided but the backend requires one (in SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256)'**
```

I am using Postgres v16

Comment: The pg_hba you show is not the one in use, or there are more lines in it than what you show.

Comment: using SSPI as the name of the map doesn't change the authentication method.  The authentication method shown in that hba excerpt is "ident", not "sspi".  But the method actually in use is asking for a password, so clearly it is neither ident nor sspi.

Comment: @jjanes - Thanks for your response. This what I read in Postgres documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF . It seemed to me that ident is the right word and there is no mention of sspi in this text. There are some other text in the pg_hba.conf

Comment: @jjanes I have added the full content of the pg_hba file section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution using the following link -

https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2034/postgres-using-integrated-security-on-windows-on-localhost

It seems to me that the application must be running on the same server as the Postgres DB. We have to have localhost on the connection string and also the username.
My problem is solved with this approach.
One open question remains - if I can connect from an application from a different server. That I would try to find out later.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "integrated security=true" in the connection strings suggest you want either SSPI or GSS.  "Ident" would not count as [integrated security](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html?tabs=tabid-1).

"Ident" is rarely used at all (it archaic and not very secure as the backchannel messages are easy to spoof).  And even more rarely used on Windows.

Your error message clearly says SCRAM is being used, so you must be hitting one of the scram lines in the pg_hba.  I guess because your supplied username does not actually equal 'domainusername' so it instead falls through to one of the 'all' lines.

If you look in the server's log file, you should see a message which is very clear about what line of the pg_hba was being used, and what the provided username was and what the authenticated username was.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I got the solution. You are right with your statements - that ident is not a correct way.